# Custom filtering in AutoCompleteTextView not working

Tags: android

I am extending the Array Adapter as it follows but I get still the old results can you please tell me what is the problem ?

```
public class Adaptor extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable{

        private ArrayList<String> items;

        public Adaptor(Context context, int textViewResourceId, String[] objects) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
            items = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < objects.length ; i++)
                items.add(objects[i]);

        }


        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }


        @Override
        public String getItem(int position) {
            return items.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            Filter myFilter = new Filter(){

                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence arg0) {
                    FilterResults rezultate = new FilterResults();
                    ArrayList<String> chestii = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.size() ; i++)
                    {
                        String tmp = items.get(i).toUpperCase();
                        if (tmp.startsWith(arg0.toString().toUpperCase()))
                                chestii.add(items.get(i));

                    }
                    rezultate.count = chestii.size();
                    rezultate.values = chestii;
                    return rezultate;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                        FilterResults results) {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0)
                    {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    else notifyDataSetInvalidated();

                }

            };
            return myFilter;
        }




    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list contains items from "items" and you don't modify items in it, you have to remove positions from "items" and then call notifyDataSetChange, to restore lately all items you have to save previous items

this is works fine:

```
/**
 * Adapter wrapper to represent list of dialogs
 * @author Ryazantsev Dmitry
 * @email dilix90@gmail.com 2012
 */
public class FriendsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<User>
{
    private final LayoutInflater inflater;
    private final ImageLoader il;
    private Context parentContext;
    private List<User> mData;
    private List<User> mOriginalData;
    public SimpleImageLoader sil;

    @Override
    public void add(User object)
    {
        if (mOriginalData != null)
            mOriginalData.add(object);
        else
            mData.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void remove(User object)
    {
        if (mOriginalData != null)
            mOriginalData.remove(object);
        else
            mData.remove(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public User getItem(int position)
    {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getPosition(User item)
    {
        return mData.indexOf(item);
    }

    public FriendsAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<User> objects)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        Log.v("refresh", context + " " + textViewResourceId + " " + objects);
        parentContext = context;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        il = new ImageLoader(context);
        mData = objects;
        sil = new SimpleImageLoader(context, true, 64);
        sil.setOnUiThread(false);
    }

    /**
     * We have a custom view and need to organize it
     */
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent)
    {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friends_list_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friendName);
            holder.root = convertView.findViewById(R.id.root);
            holder.photo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.friendPhoto);
            holder.online = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.online);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

        User user = getItem(position);
        holder.online.setVisibility(user.isOnline() > 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        if (user != null)
        {
            holder.name.setText(user.getFIO());
            holder.photo.setTag(user.getPhotoUrl());
            if (user.getPhotoBitmap() != null)
                holder.photo.setImageBitmap(user.getPhotoBitmap());
            else
            {
                holder.photo.setImageResource(R.drawable.contact_nophoto);
                sil.displayImageUserAttach(holder.photo, user.getPhotoUrl(), user, null, false, null);
            }
        }

        // parent.setVisibility(position % 2 == 0?View.GONE:View.VISIBLE);
        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView name;
        public ImageView photo;
        public View root;
        public View online;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter()
    {
        return new Filter()
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results)
            {
                Log.v("filter", "filter finished");
                mData = (List<User>) results.values;
                if (results.count > 0)
                {
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
                else
                {
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint)
            {
                Log.v("filter", "filter perform");
                if (mOriginalData == null)
                    mOriginalData = new ArrayList<User>(mData);
                List<User> result;
                FilterResults r = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() <= 0)
                    result = new ArrayList<User>(mOriginalData);
                else
                {
                    result = new ArrayList<User>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mOriginalData.size(); i++)
                        if (constraint.length() > 0
                                && mOriginalData.get(i).getFIO().toLowerCase()
                                        .contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase()))
                            result.add(mOriginalData.get(i));
                }
                r.values = result;
                r.count = result.size();
                return r;
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: So what is the purpose of FilterResults ?

Comment: You transfer data between performFiltering and publishResults. accordin to this manual: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html you filter is async and you need to devide background work and publishing and pass result to the UI thread

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged & notifyDataSetInvalidated are no longer available in android.widget.Filter?