# Android custom auto complete text view

Tags: android, autocomplete

I need to make my custom AutoCompleteTextView.
I use Unicode characters in my adapter, but the problem is that users don't always have or use keyboards with unicode chars.

The idea is when user on beginning types letter C
I will like to suggest items that starts on C,Ć,Č

When user types letter S
I will like to suggest items that starts on S and Š

Is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement you own filter and for example return not only C* values, but also C*,Ć*,Č*

How to implement your own filter you can find here

[Android AutoCompleteTextView with Custom Adapter filtering not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784249/android-autocompletetextview-with-custom-adapter-filtering-not-working)

Comment: Is there some good tutorial for that, it's little bit annoying playing with code without comments. :)

Comment: this code works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584518/custom-filtering-in-autocompletetextview-not-working/11584561#11584561 and also guides: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html and Filterable interface

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried implementing the standard Android [Search](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/index.html) Interface, but use an [FTS3/4](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html) table for suggestions with the ICU [tokenizer](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_8_1)?

I haven't implemented Unicode search yet, but using the ICU tokenizer might work. Maybe someone who has tried it can comment on this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem:

I have written this method that converts unicode string to not unicode.

```
/** Remove HTML constants for unicode chars from string */
public static String convertFromUnicode(String text, Context ctx) {

    // Find wrong unicode chars and replace it with non-unicode

    text = text.replaceAll(ch, "c");
    text = text.replaceAll(zh, "z");
    text = text.replaceAll(sh, "s");
    text = text.replaceAll(tj, "c");
    text = text.replaceAll(Ch, "C");
    text = text.replaceAll(Zh, "Z");
    text = text.replaceAll(Sh, "S");
    text = text.replaceAll(Tj, "C");

    text = text.replaceAll(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.ch), "c");
    text = text.replaceAll(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.zh), "z");
    text = text.replaceAll(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.sh), "s");
    text = text.replaceAll(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.tj), "c");
    text = text.replaceAll(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.Ch), "C");
    text = text.replaceAll(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.Zh), "Z");
    text = text.replaceAll(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.Sh), "S");
    text = text.replaceAll(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.Tj), "C");

    return text;
}
```

and in performFiltering in CustomAdaper:

```
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (constraint != null) {
            suggestions.clear();
            for (String showName : itemsAll) {

                String tempshowName = ParserData.convertFromUnicode(showName,
                        getContext());

                String tempContraint = ParserData.convertFromUnicode(
                        constraint.toString(), getContext());

                if (tempshowName.toLowerCase().startsWith(
                        tempContraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                    suggestions.add(showName);
                }
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = suggestions;
            filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
            return filterResults;
        } else {
            return new FilterResults();
        }
    }
```

So unicode and not unicode chars are seems equal. Tnx for idea @dilix.